# Is it possible to update stream chat persistence in the background in Flutter

Tags: flutter, persistence, getstream-io, getstream-chat

The chat is part of the app. The user is connected but not necessarily on the chat screen.

I would like to update the persistence of the chat when the user receives an event (new message or new channel).

Is this possible ?

Comment: Are you using the Stream chat persistence package?

Comment: @GordonHayes yes i am using stream_chat_persistence.

Comment: @GordonHayes do you have any update regarding this please ?